# Authentication Required in localhost:8080 after starting the apache-tomcat server

Tags: apache, tomcat, authentication, passwords

I am using apache-tomcat-6.0.41 on Windows 7.After starting the server I am not able to see tomcat page but a windows asking for username and password prompts up.
I have also modified the **tomcat-users.xml file** as follows:-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<tomcat-users>
   <role rolename="manager"/>
   <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager" />`
</tomcat-users>
```

**My server.xml file** also has the realm required as follows:-

```
?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"    SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />    

<GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

</GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
  <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />


     <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
     <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>


      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
       </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Can anyone suggest the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Please update the server port to a different port number such as `8050` apart from the default port `8080`. I also faced the same issue and was able to resolve it by changing the port number.

Comment: _"that will resolve issue as I also faced the same issue by changing the port no it resolved._" Little bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you are switching to new page where you are using port 8080, but *your tomcat is not actually started or not working on port 8080*.  Try changing port of tomcat instead of 8080 and check whether other service is not using 8080 port.